# Rudin Theorem 3.43 - Alternating series test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a): \vert c_1 \vert\geq\vert c_2\vert\geq \vert c_3 \vert\cdots$, $(b):c_{2m-1}\geq0,\enspace c_{2m}\leq0 \enspace(m=1,2,3,...)$, and $(c):=\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=0$. Then $\sum c_n$ converges.

What is the meaning of $(b)$? If we take a look at the alternating series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, then clearly condition $b$ is left unsatisfied. The odd terms are in fact negative, while the even terms are positive. However, ignoring $b$, we can prove this series converges using $(a)$ and $(c)$. What am I missing?

Comment: The alternating series test applies to a series whose terms have alternating  signs and are decreasing in absolute value. It does not matter if the even terms are negative and the odd terms are positive, or if it is the other way around.

Comment: (a)+(c) does *not* imply convergence, as you can see from the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore b) you cannot conclude that $\sum c_n$ is convregent, an easy counter-example being $c_n=\frac  1 n$.

The fact that $c_{2m} \geq 0$ and $c_{2m-1} \leq 0$ in your example does not affect applicabilty of the theorem. This is because $\sum c_n$ is convergent iff $\sum (-c_n)$ is convergent. The main point here is that the signs of the terms have to alternate.